# Incompatible clusterIDs in datanode and namenode

Tags: hadoop, installation

I checked solutions in this site.

I went to the (hadoop folder)/data/dfs/datanode to change ID.

but, there are not anything in datanode folder.

what can I do?

Thank for reading.

And If you help me, I will be appreciate you.

**PS**

2017-04-11 20:24:05,507 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Failed to add storage directory [DISK]file:/tmp/hadoop-knu/dfs/data/

java.io.IOException: Incompatible clusterIDs in /tmp/hadoop-knu/dfs/data: namenode clusterID = CID-4491e2ea-b0dd-4e54-a37a-b18aaaf5383b; datanode clusterID = CID-13a3b8e1-2f8e-4dd2-bcf9-c602420c1d3d

2017-04-11 20:24:05,509 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Initialization failed for Block pool  (Datanode Uuid unassigned) service to localhost/127.0.0.1:9010. Exiting.

java.io.IOException: All specified directories are failed to load.

2017-04-11 20:24:05,509 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Ending block pool service for: Block pool  (Datanode Uuid unassigned) service to localhost/127.0.0.1:9010

**core-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
    <property>
            <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
            <value>hdfs://localhost:9010</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

**hdfs-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
   <property>
            <name>dfs.replication</name>
            <value>1</value>
   </property>
   <property>
            <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
            <value>/home/knu/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.3/data/dfs/namenode</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>dfs.namenode.checkpoint.dir</name>
            <value>/home/knu/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.3/data/dfs/namesecondary</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>dfs.dataode.data.dir</name>
            <value>/home/knu/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.3/data/dfs/datanode</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>dfs.http.address</name>
            <value>localhost:50070</value>
    </property>
    <property>
           <name>dfs.secondary.http.address</name>
            <value>localhost:50090</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

**PS2**

```
[knu@localhost ~]$ ls -l /home/knu/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.3/data/dfs/
drwxrwxr-x. 2 knu knu  6  4월 11 21:28 datanode
drwxrwxr-x. 3 knu knu 40  4월 11 22:15 namenode
drwxrwxr-x. 3 knu knu 40  4월 11 22:15 namesecondary
```

Comment: Can you post your `hdfs-site.xml` and `core-site.xml`

Comment: I added hdfs-site.xml and core-site.xml

Comment: Can you also post the output of `ls -l /home/knu/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.3/data/dfs/` !!

Comment: I added the result of ls -l /home/knu/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.3/data/dfs/

Comment: oh... thx. I changed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the property name `dfs.datanode.data.dir`, it is misspelt as `dfs.dataode.data.dir`. This invalidates the property from being recognised and as a result, the default location of `${hadoop.tmp.dir}/hadoop-${USER}/dfs/data` is used as data directory.

`hadoop.tmp.dir` is `/tmp` by default, on every reboot the contents of this directory will be deleted and forces datanode to recreate the folder on startup. And thus **Incompatible clusterIDs**.

Edit this property name in `hdfs-site.xml` before formatting the namenode and starting the services.

Comment: Umm...sorry I can`t understand.
Did you say that change <name>? not <value>?

then. how can I choose the name?

Answer (score 1):

My solution :

- `rm -rf ./tmp/hadoop-${user}/dfs/data/*`
- `./bin/hadoop namenode -format`
- `./sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh start datanode`

Answer (score 0):

Try formatting the namenode and then restarting HDFS.

Comment: I did below commands

sbin/stop-all.sh 
bin/hdfs namenode -format
sbin/start-all.sh

but, datanode is still not working

Answer (score 0):

Copy the cluster under directory `/hadoop/bin$`:

```
./hdfs namenode -format -clusterId CID-a5a9348a-3890-4dce-94dc-0fec2ba999a9
```

Comment: Copy the cluster ID from datanode log and Under directory /hadoop/bin execute below command

./hdfs namenode -format -clusterId CID-a5a9348a-3890-4dce-94dc-0fec2ba999a9